# How to post data on text editor in joomla?

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a sample code:

```
$content = "";
$wysiwyg = JFactory::getEditor();
$html = $wysiwyg->display('html', $content, '100%', '400px', '', '', array(''));
```

And Jquery

```
Joomla.submitbutton = function(pressbutton) {
        if(pressbutton == 'save') {
            jQuery.ajax({
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery('#html').html('test test test');
                }
            });
        } else {
            submitform(pressbutton);
        }    
}
```

When I click submit save, text editor can't insert `test test test`, How to fix it ?

Comment: did you try this-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740610/how-to-insert-text-to-editor-programaticlly-in-joomla

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.ajax` should like

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    jQuery('#html').html('test test test');

  }
});
```

you are not using the url(page) where  to sent data so ajax call wont made and it not successful ajax request

Comment: That problem is insert text on text editor of joomla using jquery

Comment: than why you are using the ajax function ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to work with the tinyMCE object.

There you can access methods like tinyMCE.get() and others.

Check post related to tinyMCE and [tinyMCE API](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3atinymce.api.3.x)